# Keras fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train)) function takes less pictures than X_train have?

Tags: python, keras

I am using keras `fit_generator(datagen.flow())` function for training of my inception model, I am so confused about the number of images it is taking on every epoch. Can anyone please help me telling this How it is working. My code is below.

I am using [this](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) keras documentation.

```py
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range = 15, horizontal_flip = True)

# Fitting the model with
history = inc_model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train, train_labels, batch_size=10), epochs=20, validation_data = (X_test, test_labels), callbacks=None)
```

Now my total images in `X_train` is 4676. However, everytime I run this history line, I get

```py
Epoch 1/20
936/936 [========================] - 167s 179ms/step - loss: 1.4236 - acc: 0.3853 - val_loss: 1.0858 - val_acc: 0.5641
```

Why is it not taking whole of my `X_train` images? 
Also, if I change `batch_size` from 10 to lets say 15 it start taking more less images such as

```py
Epoch 1/20 
436/436
```

Thank you.

Comment: Because you are using batch. This is going to not use the entire training set for each epoch, but rather a batch of them for each epoch. This will make training faster. You could instead make `batch_size=4676` and then each epoch will train on the entire training set.

Comment: batch_size = 4676 will take huge computational power, right? but nevertheless, it will train on my whole training data not just a part of it. if I am right?

Comment: You will already be training on your entire training data. Even more since you're using `ImageDataGenerator`. Changing the `batch_size` doesn't change this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `936` and `436` actually refer to batches of samples per epoch. You set your batch size to 10 and 15, so in each case the model is trained on `936 X 10` and `436 X 15` samples per epoch. The samples is even more than your original training set, since you use the `ImageDataGenerator` which creates additional training instances by applying transformations to existing ones.